# MBP 15 2014 unexpectedly shuts down after startup/login

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup, shutdown

MacBook Pro 15, Mid 2014, Yosemite + Windows 7 (Bootcamp)

This problem started today after waking up. Yesterday night I had no problem whatsoever with my computer.

After turning it on and logging in into my profile it suddenly showed me the dialog box whether I really want to shut it down, than it turned off. I thought I accidentally pressed the power button, but it has repeated it again and again.

- I deleted all my log in items (thought maybe there could he an issue) but didn't help.
- I performed PRAM reset, didn't help.
- I've tried to boot in safe mode, but when the progress bar is about 40% it shuts down.
- I've tried to repair permissions, didn't help.

Than I ran the diagnostics in Terminal to learn what caused my shut downs. I got these two error codes:

```
Previous shutdown cause: -60 (Bad master directory block)
Previous shutdown cause: -40 (Tried to position to before start of file (r/w))
```

Any suggestion how to fix this? Anyone had similar experience?

Comment: You've possibly got a [munged up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mung#Etymology_2) hard drive _or_ corrupted directory system. Backup what you can (you _do_ use Time Machine, yes?) and see if you can reformat the HD. Because this is a Mid-14 MBP, it might still be under warrantee. To see if the disk can be repaired, boot into [single user mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) and then [run fsck manually](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203176).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried single user mode, but it turns off after running up also. My Windows Bootcamp safe mode shuts down also. Unfortunately my backup disk is not with me (I am home for the holidays) so I am doing internet restore now, my guess was also the munged up HD so I erased my disk. Waiting for the results now.

Comment: I erased my disk, tried internet recovery clean install. It shuts down during the install. It seems like a hardware issue.

Comment: So sorry. Is it still under warrantee?

Comment: 3 month old. I purchased it because my MBP 2011 stopped working because of graphics card issues. 1 month after I purchased the retina one, they started to offer free replacement for the 2011 model. Now I am stuck with two broken MBPs. And I am stuck with work also. I don't think I could be a less satisfied customer.