# MBP 15" early 2011 shuts down after login without power cord

Tags: battery, power, shutdown

Update #1:

> I uninstalled gfxcardstatus. Now the only times it shuts down instantly
>   are when I initially log in (tried on user with Filevault and one
>   without), and when I log out from one user and log into another.  I've unplugged while logged in, I've put it to sleep and
>   come back, I've logged out and back in (as same user), and it stays on. It always
>   shuts down if I log in from a fresh reboot.

I've seen issues where the [MBP shuts down after login](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179739/mbp-15-2014-unexpectedly-shuts-down-after-startup-login), and where the [MBA shuts down without power](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124839/fully-charged-macbook-air-turns-off-when-power-cord-removed), but this is just a little different.

The computer works fine when plugged in. No issues. The problem comes up when it's unplugged. This started just after I updated to 10.10.4, although I don't know whether it's related.

1. Start computer with or without battery, get to login screen.
2. Can maintain this state for minutes at a time plugged in or on battery on login screen.
3. When I log in, the computer's immediate action is to shut down. Screen just goes dark -- no warnings, no nothing.

Any ideas? SMC reset did not help. Magsafe light looks yellow or green as is appropriate to charging situation. No other weird behaviors or warning signs.

System information -> power shows nothing weird:

```
Charge Information:
Charge Remaining (mAh):   5955
Fully Charged:    No
Charging: Yes
Full Charge Capacity (mAh):   6547
Health Information:
Cycle Count:  143
Condition:    Normal
Battery Installed:    Yes
Amperage (mA):    1337
Voltage (mV): 12468
```

I get no notification of any kind after it starts again as is described by [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92099/macbook-randomly-shuts-down-without-on-charge-even-at-90-full?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

It might be your GPU.  Try going to System Preferences->Energy Saver and changing the "Graphics" setting.  If it was on "Better battery life" then set it to "Higher performance", and vice-versa if it already was on "Higher performance".

Comment: One other thing you might want to have a look at, since it may be a possible cause of your problem.
https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Comment: I discovered something else weird and new, see update #1 above. My computer is indeed one of those affected, similar to the beloved Thinkpad T61p which it replaced. Tried all this with both settings as @user128998 suggested.

Comment: If you boot into Safe mode, do you still have the same problem?  If not, then it might be due to some login item that is launched when you first log into a user account.